# Extent Report getting overwritten instead of getting appended for multiple tests

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, extentreports

I am using `Extent Report Version 4.0.9` to generate report for two of my tests. I am working on selenium, java, testng, cucumber, maven project. I have two TestRunner files in my cucumberOptions which I run one after the other using `POM.xml`. 
When I run only one TestRunner, the Extent Report gets generated as expected. But when I run both TestRunners one after the other, the Extent Report which is generated by the second test overwrites the one generated by the first one.
How do I append the ExtentReport generated by the second test to that generated by the first test?

Here is my ExtentReporterListener code:

```
public class ExtentReporterListener {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ExceptionHandler.class);
    private static final String TEST_OUTPUT = TestConfiguration.USER_DIR + "\\test-output\\Screenshots";

    public static ExtentHtmlReporter report = null;
    public static ExtentReports extent = null;
    public static ExtentTest feature = null;
    public static ExtentTest scenario = null;

    public static ExtentReports setUp() {
        String reportLocation = "./Reports/Extent_Report.html";

        report = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);
        report.config().setDocumentTitle("Word press Automation Test Report");
        report.config().setReportName("Word Press Automation Test Report");
        report.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        log.info("Extent Report location initialized...");
        report.start();

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(report);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Application", "Word Press");

        return extent;
    }
}

This is my testng.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name = "listener-class" />
  </listeners>
  <test thread-count="5" name="frontEnd">
  <parameter name="URL" value="front-end-url" />
    <classes>
      <class name="frontendTestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test thread-count="5" name="Backend">
  <parameter name="URL" value="back-end-url" /> 
    <classes>
      <class name="backendtestrunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test>  <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I am using Extent Report version 4. Somehow `setAppendExisting(true);` method which was in older version doesnot seem to exist in version 4.

Comment: Please add date and time to the reporting file using    import java.time.LocalTime;
String reportLocation = "./Reports/Extent_Report_" + LocalTime.now() + ".html";

Comment: @PankajDevrani: But wouldn't doing that generate two separate reports? I want a single report, the result of the second one appended to the result of the first one.

Comment: Sorry about misinterpretation. Can you try initializing reports at class level or assembly level instead of doing it and TestMethod level? I am not sure exactly at what level reports are getting initialized.

Comment: Is there any way i can merge the two reports that are generated after both my extent reports are generated? or is there is method in Extent Reports version 4.0.9 which does same job as "setAppendExisting(true);" which was there in Extent Reports version 3?

Comment: Yes you can do that but in order to do that you need to initializing and cleanup reports at assembly level and not test method level. Call the setup method at assembly level initialization and close the report at assembly level cleanup.

Comment: @PankajDevrani: Thankyou for replying. I am very new to Selenium and Extent Reports. I don't understand what you mean by assembly level. Do you mean BeforeSuite and AfterSuite?

Comment: Yes. That will work too. I think please try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

After the below line of code please make the append existing as true.

```
report = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);
report.setAppendExisting(true);
```

This will append the tests after execution.

Comment: Its not working, I couldnt see method or property as setAppendExisting(true);

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem of ExtentReport getting overwritting when I changed my testng.xml like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name = "listener-class" />
  </listeners>
  <test thread-count="5" name="frontEnd">
    <classes>
      <class name="frontendTestRunner">
          <parameter name="URL" value="front-end-url" />
      </class>
      <class name="backendtestrunner">
           <parameter name="URL" value="back-end-url" />
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```